# Creating object from a private inner class

Tags: java

I have a class and contain many inner classes 
one of this inner class is a subclass and has many children 
like this :

```
class BigClass {
    A a;
    B b;
    C c[] = new C[3];

    class A {}

    class B {
       A a1;
    }

    class C {
        B b1;
    }

    class c1 extends C {}

    class c2 extends C {}

    class c3 extends C {}
}
```

How do I make an object from a BigClass when all the classes are linked to each either ?

Comment: First please fix your code indentation so that it is easy to read. Edit: done, but in the future, please do this yourself.

Comment: Linked to each other like what? Please provide more information. If you want to make an instance of class `Whatever`, just do `Whatever w = new Whatever();`, no matter if it contains inner classes.

Comment: On the first glance it looks like quite ugly Java code IMHO

Comment: class A give me a value uses in class B ,also class B give me a value use in class C

Comment: You mean have a `BigClass` constructor that does `a = new A(); b = new B(); b.a1 = a; c[0] = new c1(); c.b1 = b;`, and so on?  Like that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a working method that demonstrates how to instantiate each class and assign the variables. Add this method to your `BigClass` class so you can run it as a program.

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
     BigClass big = new BigClass();

     A a = big.new A();
     big.a = a;

     B b = big.new B();
     b.a1 = a;
     big.b = b;

     C c = big.new C();
     c.b1 = b;
     big.c[0] = c;

     c1 c1 = big.new c1();
     big.c[0] = c1;

     c2 c2 = big.new c2();
     big.c[1] = c2;

     c3 c3 = big.new c3();
     big.c[2] = c3;
}
```